# I can't read persian Character in R

Tags: r, csv, persian

I provide some columns attribute and its values in persian language in csv and alse Txt Unicode Format. but when I read it in R, all persian values would be nonsense.after running code I see below:
in console:

```
data=read.csv("E:/ais/salar (2).csv",header = T, encoding="UTF-8")



      ï..Ù.Ø.Ù. Ù.Ø.Ù..Ø.Ø.Ù.Ù.Ø.Ø.Ú.ÛŒ ØªÙ.Ù.Ù..Ø.Ø.Ø.Øª
1  Ø¯Ú©ØªØ± ØºÙ„Ø§Ù…Ø±Ø¶Ø§      Ù‚Ø§Ø³Ù…ÛŒ Ø«Ø§Ù†ÛŒ   +9821 6616 6626
2  Ø¯Ú©ØªØ± ØºÙ„Ø§Ù…Ø±Ø¶Ø§      Ù‚Ø§Ø³Ù…ÛŒ Ø«Ø§Ù†ÛŒ   +9821 6616 6626
3  Ø¯Ú©ØªØ± ØºÙ„Ø§Ù…Ø±Ø¶Ø§      Ù‚Ø§Ø³Ù…ÛŒ Ø«Ø§Ù†ÛŒ   +9821 6616 6626
4  Ø¯Ú©ØªØ± ØºÙ„Ø§Ù…Ø±Ø¶Ø§      Ù‚Ø§Ø³Ù…ÛŒ Ø«Ø§Ù†ÛŒ   +9821 6616 6626
5  Ø¯Ú©ØªØ± ØºÙ„Ø§Ù…Ø±Ø¶Ø§      Ù‚Ø§Ø³Ù…ÛŒ Ø«Ø§Ù†ÛŒ   +9821 6616 6626
```

Comment: Hi modarzi, [this](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6140/reading-persian-characters-in-r) question looks similar to yours (although there is not accepted answer).

Also, might the `farsi` package be of any use (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/farsi/farsi.pdf))?

Comment: Or the `persiandictionary` package. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/persiandictionary/persiandictionary.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

try using encoding="UTF-8" while reading your file

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but as you see in my question I used this agument 'encoding="UTF-8" '.unfortunately again I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too...
without including encoding, I give something like these:

```
    a <- read.csv("./data500000-960331.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

    [1] Þã                 ÓíÓÊÇä æÈáæÓÊÇä   åãÏÇä              Þã                
   [5] ÝÇÑÓ               ÎÑÇÓÇä ÑÖæÆ        ÇÕÝåÇä             áÓÊÇä            
   [9] ÝÇÑÓ               áÓÊÇä             åÑãÒÇä            ÂÐÑÈÇíÌÇä ÔÑÞí    
  [13] ÂÐÑÈÇíÌÇä ÛÑÈí     ßÑãÇäÔÇå
```

and by including encoding:

```
    a <- read.csv("./data500000-960331.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", encoding = "UTF-8")
    enter code here
    [3] \xe5\xe3\xcf\xc7\xe4                                                   
   [4] \xde\xe3                                                               
   [5] \xdd\xc7\xd1\xd3                                                       
   [6] \xce\xd1\xc7\xd3\xc7\xe4 \xd1\xd6\xe6\xc6                              
   [7] \xc7\xd5\xdd\xe5\xc7\xe4                                               
   [8] \u0090\xe1\xd3\xca\xc7\xe4                                             
   [9] \xdd\xc7\xd1\xd3                                                       
  [10] \u0090\xe1\xd3\xca\xc7\xe4                                             
  [11] \xe5\xd1\xe3Ґ\xc7\xe4                                                  
  [12] \xc2\xd0\xd1\xc8\xc7\xed\xcc\xc7\xe4 \xd4\xd1\xde\xed                  
  [13] \xc2\xd0\xd1\xc8\xc7\xed\xcc\xc7\xe4 \xdb\xd1\xc8\xed
```